# protractor test for a video tag

Tags: angularjs, video, protractor, html5-video

I am fairly new to front end land, so bear with me... I have an HTML page with an embedded video through an HTML video tag like so:

```
<video id=... class=...>
    <source src=... type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This video resets back to the beginning when it is done playing.  Now I would like to test this using protractor.  Currently I can get the element, but I do not know how to play/pause the video, see how far along the video is, etc. from a protractor test.  I can get the element through `element(by.id('<id>'))` and I can do the normal stuff like seeing if it is visible, click on it, etc. but have no idea how to get at the guts of the element.

UPDATE:

The issue with this is that the controls are provided by the browser as my video tag specifies the 'controls' attribute.  That means the play/pause button is not part of the DOM and hence why I cannot get to it.  Also, the browser is the one that sends an event to say that the video has ended.  So, in order for me to test that the video resets after it has ended, I would need to hit the play button which is not listed as a DOM object.  Is there a way to trigger an 'ended' event without playing the video?  Or can I trigger it by setting the currentTime attribute to the duration attribute somehow?

Answer (score 1):

you can't select play/pause controls by selectors , instead you can add a button by your own and add HTML audio/video events to it . So that you can automate using that button.

```
button.onclick = function () {
   (videoSelector).play/pause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hawari Abdulla

Answer (score 0):

To play the video you will have to select the 'play' button from the 'DOM' rather than the video tag by id say element(by.css('<.class of play button>'))
and if its present in the callback of isPresent() add the click event. To give a complete answer it will be good to have a snapshot of the 'DOM' at the time when video is played.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get a snapshot of the 'DOM' printed out or something?  As the play button is within the video tag and I cannot see what class it is, I am not sure how to call `element(by.css('<class of play button>'))`

Comment: I tried `element(by.css('btn btn-default'))`, but nothing was found

Answer (score 0):

The best option i found at the moment is using plain javascript to automate the 
execution of pausing, playing, etc. adding the following code either in a page object or a spec:

```
    browser.executeScript(function () {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.play();
    });
```